# Category and subcategory control which single post template should load?

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

here is the scenario
I have 2 (or more) categories and each has 5 (or more) subcategories

cat1 – veg (subcat: 1) carrot 2) tomato etc
cat2 – fruit (subcat: 1) apple 2) orange etc

I have created for each category single templates:
single-veg.php, single-fruit.php ..

So, does anyone know what should be the correct function to load single-veg.php on all posts which belong to subcategories: ‘veg’, ‘carrot’ etc category??

This is what I have adopted, but I think there must be a better way.. and of course, if you notice anything wrong with the code… I am newbie
any help would be appreciated

```
/** Get Post Category and sub category */

function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null )
{
    foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
        // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
        $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category');
        if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Conditional Templates for Single posts */

function template_change( $template ){

    if( is_single() && (post_is_in_descendant_category('12')) || in_category('12') ){
        $templates = array("single-veg.php");
    }
   elseif( is_single() && (post_is_in_descendant_category('17')) || in_category('17') ){
        $templates = array("single-fruit.php");
    } elseif( is_single() && in_category('articles') ){
        $templates = array("single-articles.php");
    }
    $template = locate_template( $templates );
    return $template;
}

add_filter( 'single_template', 'template_change' ); //'template_include'/'single_template'
```

Answer (score 0):

1) **Using Post Formats:**

First of all You can create different post format for both categories (put following in functions.php):

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'single-veg', 'single-fruit' ) );
```

Now you can use post formats. You can select a post-format in admin area for each post and then call following in single.php to load different files for each format.

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_format( 'single-veg' )) {
        get_template_part( 'content', 'single-veg' ); // includes content-single-veg.php
    } else if ( has_post_format( 'single-fruit' )) {
        get_template_part( 'content', 'single-fruit' ); // includes content-single-fruit.php
    }
?>
```

2) **Using category slugs:**
    If 'single-veg' and 'single-fruit' are category slugs, put following condition to load 2 different files in single.php based on category slugs.

```
<?php
if(in_category('single-veg')) {
  get_template_part( 'content', 'single-veg' ); // includes content-single-veg.php
}
elseif(in_category('single-fruit')) {
  get_template_part( 'content', 'single-fruit' ); // includes content-single-fruit.php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will try both methods.  And am I right, it will work for sub categories as well?

Comment: Hi, it did not work :( maybe I am doing something wrong but I better check,   is your code  for single post template? OR custom post type template?  I am using only single template at the moment    thanks again for your support


Could the problem be that I am using a child theme (genesis framework)?

Comment: It should work on single template, but i am not aware of child theme effect here. Could you please describe which step you are getting problem. for example you have defined post format in admin, assigned post-format to posts, and then are you able to check it in single.php using "has_post_format"?

Comment: I suppose, the reason it is not working, is because I do not use post type formats. just plain old style wordpress posts and categories

Comment: For Solutions 1) you need to use post-formats and let me tell you custom post type is different thing. post-format options can be found in default posts as well. 'aside', 'link', 'audio' etc are some defaults while you can add your own such as: add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'single-veg', 'single-fruit' ) );
For more: http://webdesignledger.com/tips/getting-started-with-wordpress-post-formats

Comment: I am also getting problem in defining new post-formats. It looks like we can only use from earlier such as aside, video, image etc to differentiate theme.